# Movie where a convict takes over a spaceship and a pool shark is unfrozen to land it

Tags: story-identification, movie

I believe this movie is Canadian-made, late 1990s to early 2000s.

A convict takes over a spaceship and the hero unfreezes a pool shark from cryo to land the ship after unfreezing the wrong brother.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  You're saying that the hero intended to defrost someone else, but got the pool shark by mistake?

Answer (score 3):

I almost hesitate to suggest it, since the reviews are dire, but [*Starfire Mutiny*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0337724/) (2002) seems to match the details you've noted.  Quoting from an [extensive review](https://www.imdb.com/review/rw2360304/):

> Would-be dictator **General Montgomery Swan (Douglas Arthurs) takes over Legacy, after he's broken out of prison** by his right-hand woman Colonel Diana Briggs (Maureen LaVette). Now, Swan's prison was on Earth. It held many other prisoners and was staffed by several soldiers so, it's clear that human beings can and do survive and live on the desolate planet. Why then go through the rigmarole of freezing people and shooting them into orbit? That's one of those questions you're not supposed to ask.
>
> Swan wants to replace the energy of the solar flare with a nuclear explosion that destroys the part of legacy with all the frozen folks, restoring the Earth and making him its supreme leader. How exactly would he become the supreme leader when his forces consist of a hard-faced woman and three thugs who are as much comic relief as military muscle? That's another one of those questions you're not supposed to ask.
>
> Opposing Swan and company are **square-jawed space station commander Sam Talbot (Joe Lara)**, cryogenic technician and **pool-playing horndog** Ben Gunn (Julius Krajewski) and a small-time con woman (Elise Muller) who scammed her way on the station in place of the physicist leading the effort to fix the ozone layer. They're joined by a couple of unfrozen bimbos (portrayed by "actresses" who had to have done many unpleasant things with the fat and sweaty producers who demanded they be shoehorned into the film).